# Using JUnit Categories runner with matchAny with Maven Surefire from command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have 2 filters for my JUnit tests that I want to intersect: priorities(e.g. high, medium, low) and features (e.g. account, shop, checkout).
The JUnit Categories runner seems perfect for this, since it supports a `matchAny` flag, it could do the intersecting filter I need (e.g. return tests that are flagged as both 'high' priority AND 'checkout' feature, doing an AND not an OR).

I am using Maven Surefire to execute tests, which supports JUnit categories through its corresponding `groups` parameter. This works:

```
mvn test -Dgroups="priority.High, feature.Checkout"
```

Unfortunately it applies the default `matchAny` value which is `true`, resulting in an OR combination, not AND.

**Question**: How can I pass `matchAny=false` through Surefire command line?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, not supported by surefire plugin nor feasible via the opposite approach (using `excludedGroups` and fo cli ease in combination with profiles and properties).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `matchAny=false`. Just do as follows:

```
mvn test -Dgroups="priority.High && feature.Checkout"
```

This should run those tests having only both categories specified.